# Bootstrap 3, use toggle with grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I was trying to find out if it was possible to be able to hide and toggle a grid system in Bootstrap 3, like you can with the navbar? As in, with the navbar you can have it hidden at a smaller screen size, and extend when an icon is clicked, to show all of the links.

I decided to turn a site's navigation into a grid system, and omitted the navbar so I could achieve a certain look, but now in smaller screens, I don't want the links to be necessarily visible the entire time so it doesn't clutter. They stack on top of each other vertically, rather nicely, but it takes up a lot of space.

I hope that makes sense...

**This is the html hierarchy I am using for the grid system. I only included one of six columns as to not have a ton of code here since they're exactly the same per column. Please let me know if there is any other code I would need to show**

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px; background-color: #1a83a3; ">

    <div class="col-md-2">

      <div class="list-group" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">

        <a class="list-group-item" href="index.html">

          <h4 class="linky">About Us</h4>

          <p class="nav">Our Community</p>

        </a>

      </div><!-- END OF LISTGROUP -->
    </div><!-- END OF COL -->
  </div><!-- END OF ROW -->
</div><!-- END OF CONTAINER -->
```

Comment: have a look at the documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed -- to hide like they do in navbar, you'll need to use collapse, too: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse 
If you want to see how they actually did the navbar, there's a good example in the docs too: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: I'll play around with it and see if I can get that to work! Thank you!